# Will it Repaint?

Tags: pine-script

I just found this script and it looks good on the chart, actually, it seems too good to be true! so I thought it was repainting! so can you guys help me out with it? dose it repaints?

```
//@version=2
//Heikin Ashi Strategy  V2 by breizh29

strategy("Heikin Ashi Strategy  V2",shorttitle="HAS V2",overlay=true,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.EUR)
res = input(title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="60")
hshift = input(1,title="Heikin Ashi Candle Time Frame Shift")
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="180")
mhshift = input(0,title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame Shift")
fama = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Period")
test = input(1,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(30,"Slow EMA Period")
slomas = input(1,"Slow EMA Shift")
macdf = input(false,title="With MACD filter")
res2 = input(title="MACD Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="15")
macds = input(1,title="MACD Shift")




//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_open = security(ha_t, res, open[hshift])
ha_close = security(ha_t, res, close[hshift])
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, close[mhshift])

//macd
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdl = security(ha_t,res2,macdLine[macds])
macdsl= security(ha_t,res2,signalLine[macds])

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],fama)
sma = ema(ha_close[slomas],sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=lime,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=red,linewidth=2,style=line)


//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) and (macdl > macdsl or macdf == false )
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma) and (macdl < macdsl or macdf == false )

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks too good because you use heikin ashi chart for a strategy, which seriously distorts the backtest. You should never backtest on anything rather than regular chart.

Regarding repainting: it most likely will repaint at some point because of use of **ema** function, which is prone to repainting.

Answer (score 0):

You're using candle close functions like crossover and crossunder
I think the script doesn't repaint